# Costmap2DROS transform timeout

Tags: ros, timeout, costmap-2d-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run amcl, move_base and map_server on my robot. Everything starts fine but after I get "Odom received" warning messages start to show up:

> Costmap2DROS transform timeout.
> Current time: 1438775060.1538,
> global_pose stamp: 1438775056.1344,
> tolerance: 0.3000

and

> [ WARN] [1438775074.022202129]:
> MessageFilter [target=map
> base_laser_link ]: Dropped 100.00% of
> messages so far. Please turn the
> [ros.costmap_2d.message_notifier]
> rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more
> information.

They come from the Costmap2D plugin. I runned tf_monitor and I got:

```
RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
Frame: /base_footprint published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.0456822 Max Delay: 0.10752
Frame: base_front_laser_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.545968 Max Delay: 0
Frame: base_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.545971 Max Delay: 0
Frame: base_rear_laser_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.545966 Max Delay: 0
Frame: odom published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.108352 Max Delay: 0.0916446

All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 82.2074 Hz, Average Delay: -0.360456 Max Delay: 0.10752
```

What could be the problem causing the timeout?

When viewing the frames, I see that robot_state_publisher publishes with 50 Hz but somehow all published links have a delay of -0.5 seconds, which cannot be possible!

[image: image description]

I kept looking at it in real time with tf_monitor and the time of the most recent transform from robot_state_publisher is -0.5 for some time, then it jumps to +0.5. This is very confusing.

I kept tf_monitor running for few minutes and it seems like the delays are increasing:

```
RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
Frame: /base_footprint published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 2.57823 Max Delay: 17.9659
Frame: base_front_laser_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.408636 Max Delay: 0.626485
Frame: base_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.40864 Max Delay: 0.626482
Frame: base_rear_laser_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.408634 Max Delay: 0.626486
Frame: odom published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 3.65717 Max Delay: 16.6323

All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 82.0346 Hz, Average Delay: -0.124652 Max Delay: 1.20379
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215256/costmap2dros-transform-timeout/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-08-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anna_26](https://answers.ros.org/users/22815/anna_26/) on 2015-10-01**:
Did you solve it?how to solve this(Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1438775060.1538, global_pose stamp: 1438775056.1344, tolerance: 0.3000).
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can change the tolerance of the tf listener when you declare it, for example for a tolerance of 10 seconds just do         self.tf_listener = tf.TransformListener(10) but this is just for debugging and is not a good idea for long term use.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tomkimsour](https://answers.ros.org/users/73888/tomkimsour/) on 2021-05-11**:
Where are you supposed to put this line ?
I have this error but only use yaml and launch files